# Tests must be run on a concrete device

Tags: swift, xctest

I am trying to run test cases of custom framework . When I tried to run on physical device I got below error mentioned below.

```
xcodebuild \ -scheme Automation \ -destination'generic/platform=iOS' \ test
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "generic" destination. You need to use any supported device specifier, e.g.:

```bash
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro Max,OS=16.2'
```